# Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] ~ since I tried previous ans but not able to resolve it

Tags: reactjs, web-development-server

I am making a chat application
and got following error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHACW.png)

I tried several things but don't get success. If anyone require more code please comment me.

userController.js=

```
const asyncHandler=require("express-async-handler")//to handle errors
const User=require('../models/userModel')
const generateToken=require('../config/generateToken')

const registerUser=asyncHandler(async(req,res)=>{
    const{name,email,password,pic}=req.body;

    if(!name || !email || !password){
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error("Please Enter all the fields");
    }//handling errors
const userExists=await User.findOne({email})//query in MongoDB

    if(userExists){
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error("User already exists");
    }

    const user=await User.create({
        name,
        email,
        password,
        pic,

    });//create user in DB
if(user){
    res.status(201).json({
        _id: user._id,
        name:user.name,
        email:user.email,
        pic:user.pic,
        token:generateToken(user._id),
    });
}
else{
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Failed to Create user")
}
});

module.exports={registerUser}
```

server.js=

```
- const express = require("express");
- const dotenv = require("dotenv");
- const { chats } = require("./data/data");
- const connectDB = require("./config/db");
- const colors = require("colors");
- const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes").default;
- 
- dotenv.config();
- connectDB();
- const app = express(); //creating an instance of express
- 
- app.use(express.json()); //to accept json data
- 
- app.get("/", (req, res) => {
- res.send("API is Running");
- - });
- 
- app.use("/api/user", userRoutes);
- 
- const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
- 
- app.listen(5000, console.log(`Server started on Port {5000}`.yellow.bold));
```

I tried by checking import and export of all the required files but won't get success